# Why am I getting an invalid literal error?

Tags: python, int, pyqt4, string

I need to split a two digit value from a pyqt spinbox in half for math operations. In order to do this I'm converting the value to a string. This works fine for the first digit and it goes back to an integer without a problem. The second digit however won't convert back and keeps throwing a base 10 invalid literal error. What am I doing wrong? I have the decimal place set to 0 so I don't think it's that.

```
         w1 = self.doubleSpinBox_12.value()
         w2 = self.doubleSpinBox_13.value()

         w1a = str(w1)
         w1b = w1a[:1]
         w1c = int( w1b) * 12

         w1b2 = w1a[1:]
         w1b3 = int( w1b2) 



         w = w1c + w1b3
         print w
```

Comment: can you post the exception?  are you sure the value of `w12b` is what you're expecting?  [1:] gets *everything* after the first digit, perhaps make that [1:2]?

Comment: have you, maybe, some example values?

Comment: thx j.j. you're right. I'm not certain why but changing it to [1:2] worked.

Answer (score 0):

To find out what's going on throw some `print`s in there:

```
w1b2 = w1a[1:]
print(repr(w1b2))
```

then you can see exactly what's in there, including whatever characters are not base 10 valid literals.